# Deleting answers with a positive rep balance

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-posts

The related question:

[What do you call all the pieces of a song minus the lyrics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323458/what-do-you-call-all-the-pieces-of-a-song-minus-the-lyrics/323459#323459)

My answer was:

> Basically, I'd go for 'Music'. But I might be wrong, but I might be right?

(the second sentence is an idea borrowed from PiL - Rise: http://www.songlyrics.com/pil/rise-lyrics/)

and I got 9 upvotes and 6 downvotes.

Can someone tell me why me post was deleted, costing me 78 rep points?

My answer had received numerous upvotes. How does anyone have the right to delete an answer that has earned the user rep points? As this is a community site, and the community has decided an answer is worthwhile, then this surely ought to take precedence.

Comment: See [Why did I delete your answer?](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2015/11/why-did-i-delete-your-answer/).

Comment: @MattE.Эллен; that applies to 0.5 of the answers on SE, and if i cant use the word 'music'?

Comment: You can use the word *music*, just explain your answer fully.

Comment: I am sorry for your loss, but it would not have been deleted if you had followed @NVZ's advice. The answer is too short.

Comment: You received a total  of nine upvotes and six downvotes, i.e.   90 - 12 = 78 And it's likely the answer received more than one flag, presumably for low quality

Comment: @JJJ No, that's no duplicate, it's completely unrelated. I don't have the rep to see deleted posts, but the comments clearly point to JonMark's answer being deleted (presumably for low quality) and he was bemoaning the loss of the points that his answer had accumulated. The post you link to is about losing rep when a *user is removed*, which is entirely different.

Comment: JonMarkPerry is there a reason why you edited your post? Did you want your question on meta to be re-evaluated or attract greater attention? The solution is simple, edit your deleted post, write a full proper answer–not consisting of one word–and ask one of the mods to undelete it. By the way, the line about maybe you're right, maybe you're wrong, went way over my head and perhaps for others too. I don't think it's a particular famous song lyric, a link, or saying "quoting from blah, blah," might have dissuaded (not saying it would) a few of the downvoters.

Comment: @Mari-LouA; when I re-looked at the post, there was a 'duplicate' issue, one of the options was 'no, I disagree this post is a dupe, please edit and tick no' sort of thing, which I did. It's not a famous song, I never said it was, I just like it.

Comment: Ahh, now I get it. You edited *after* JJJ had voted to close it as a dupe. You did well, in that case. Back to the original query: The problem with your answer was that you *never* explained anything. Which is kinda ironic seeing as you're asking for an explanation of the deletion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA; I've edited my answer now as well, hopefully it now explains my logic.

Comment: Don't forget to flag it and ask the mods to undelete it. You could edit the meta post, add this addendum to it. Good luck. P.S. Google is *not* a dictionary, cite the proper one! P.P.S Add a link too.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен The author has edited their answer to be a reasonable one and doesn't deserve to be deleted. However, since a mode (you) deleted it, the system doesn't allow those with quasi-mod powers to undelete it. Can you please undelete this answer?

Comment: @Mitch yes, I can.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Excellent, thanks.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yay! reopened. To be honest, your first answer was crap. No it is a good answer. I don't know if it is worth 9 upvotes, but it isn't now worth 6 down. Unfortunately, those voters are unlikely to notice that change. This meta question though... it originally was also a bit... needy. Now it is an OK question (and was acted upon). The title though is still ... needy, which probably accounts for its downvotes.

Answer (score 9):

As the comments above suggest, your answer was flagged as low-quality and therefore removed by the community (or by a moderator, perhaps. [See why](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2015/11/why-did-i-delete-your-answer/)).

I recall that I had posted a comment asking you to improve your answer, but you didn't pay attention. The up-votes you got were because it was a good *suggestion* (i.e. music). The down-votes were probably because it was not a good *answer*; it showed a lack of effort.

You have enough rep and badges, so I'm sure you know what a good answer is supposed to be. And if you would rather suggest a word without any explanation, use the *comments* section, so that someone else may use your suggestion to write a detailed answer themselves.

Comment: I like your answer, especially the last part.

Comment: @Rathony Thank you, and I've a slight confusion. Should it be "themself" instead of "themselves"?

Comment: +1 for a good answer. [Themselves or themself is unnecessary. However, to answer your question: "someone else.......detailed answer themself"  or "others may use....detailed answers themselves."]

Comment: For more (and much, much better) on themselves/themself, see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216617/the-hidden-flaw-in-singular-they-what-to-do-about-reflexive-pronouns  Excellent question, excellent comments and terrific answers.

Comment: @ab2 thank you. Amazing answers there. :)